# top chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, chern-classes

Let $E\to M$ be a  holomorphic vector bundle ($M$ is compact) and assume $s\colon M\to E$ is a non-trivial section transverse to the zero section.

Is it be possible that $s^{-1}(0)\neq \emptyset$, yet $c_{top}(E)=0$?

I exect the answer to be NO. If $M$ is Kahler, integrating the Kahler form on $s^{-1}(0)$ shows that it is homologically non-trivial.
But how do you prove it for general complex manifold or without using the Kahler form.

Comment: The 'diagonal section of the trivial line bundle on $\mathbb C$ gives an example, no?

Comment: I should have said M is compact.

Comment: I suggest looking at the Hironaka twist, an example of a non-projective smooth proper threefold (Hartshorne B 3.4.1). It has two smooth disjoint curves $M_1$ and $M_2$ with the property that $M_1+M_2$ is numerically trivial. It could be possible to construct a rank 2 vector bundle $E$ with a section $s$ whose zero scheme is $M_1+M_2$.

Comment: OK, you think counter examples of this sort exist! I should look at this example.

Comment: If $E$ is a line bundle, then you can use a Gauduchon metric to show that if $s^{-1}(0)\neq\emptyset$, then $c_1(E)\neq 0$. Gauduchon metrics exist on any compact complex manifolds.

Comment: The result is trivial for a line bundle : if a section does not vanish, it is a generator, hence the line bundle is trivial.

Comment: Here is a counterexample to your question. Take $X$ to be an Enoki surface, it has a cycle of rational curves, call it $D$, such that $D^2=0$, and the class induced by $D$ in the singular cohomology $H^2(X, {\mathbb R})$ is $0$. The line bundle $E$ induced by $D$ hence has a section whose zero-set is $D$, non-empty, and its Chern class is zero in $H^2(X,{\mathbb R})$. You can use a Gauduchon metric to show that its class is non-zero in the Bott-Chern cohomology.

Comment: @user20497: Aren't the Chern classes $c_k$ defined in $H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{Z})$?  Maybe the class of $D$ is a torsion class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @user20497: a cycle of rational curves is not a transverse section (transverse sections are smooth).

Comment: @Jason You're right. But here is another example, hope it works: it's a primary Hopf surface $X$, Harvey and Lawson call it of class $0$ in their 1983 Inventiones paper. There exists a smooth elliptic curve $T\subset X$ such that $[T]$ (the current induced by integrating on $T$) is $d$-exact. The Hopf surface is $S^3\times S^1$ from the differential point of view, so there is no torsion in $H^*(X,{\mathbb Z})$. The line bundle $E={\mathcal O}_X(T)$ associated to $T$ satisfies $c_1(E)=0\in H^2(X,{\mathbb Z})$.  Probably the non-Kahler elliptic surfaces have the same property.

Comment: @user20497:  That example definitely works, since $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Take a Hopf surface $H$, projected to ${\Bbb C}P^1$ with fibers elliptic curves, and let $L=\pi^* O(1)$ be a pullback of $O(1)$ from ${\Bbb C}P^1$ to $H$. Since $H=S^3\times S^1$, all line bundles are topologically trivial, but $L$ has sections (pulled back from ${\Bbb C} P^1$) vanishing somewhere on $H$.